# How to access first value from array in Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This is the array

```
["236.jpg","239.jpg","294.jpg","748.jpg","157.jpg","446.jpg","871.jpg","778.jpg"]
```

I want to access

> "236.jpg"

. The code right below which I am using to fetch the top array.Now how can I fetch the first item using below code ?

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in p">
    <td>
     {{ x.images }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please help me to find out the sollution.

For more here is the full code

```
{"info":[{"id":"11","name":"brown","description":"fasdfasd","size":"fasdf","color":"5a72fb","created_at":"2015-09-08 22:33:33","updated_at":"2015-09-08 22:33:33","images":"[\"236.jpg\",\"239.jpg\",\"294.jpg\",\"748.jpg\",\"157.jpg\",\"446.jpg\",\"871.jpg\",\"778.jpg\"]"},{"id":"13","name":"fasdf","description":"asdfghjkl","size":"fasdf","color":"5a72fb","created_at":"2015-09-09 11:48:31","updated_at":"2015-09-09 11:48:31","images":"[\"910.jpg\",\"504.jpg\",\"784.jpg\"]"}]}


angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
      $http.get('test').success(function (data){
        $scope.p = angular.fromJson(data);
        console.log(angular.fromJson(data));
      });
});

<tbody ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <tr ng-repeat="x in p">
    <td ng-if="x.images ">
        {{ x.images | limitTo:$index }}
    </td>
    <td>{{ x.size }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now please help me with full code. Thank you.

Comment: you could use `ng-if="$first"` inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: check here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat... check Oliver Smith's answer. He got it.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please give me a sollution

Answer (score 20):

Well just doing the following will work:

```
<td>
    {{p[0]}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do it.
One way would be to use **filter** limitTo:1 with ng-repeat.

Try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in p | |limitTo:1">
    <td>
     {{ x.images }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Should it not be "x in p |limitTo:1" ?

Answer (score 1):

For your condition, you can use `ng-if` inside `ng-repeat` as Pankaj said in the comment.

```js
  var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', []);
  app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.p = {
      "info": [{
        "id": "11",
        "name": "brown",
        "description": "fasdfasd",
        "size": "fasdf",
        "color": "5a72fb",
        "created_at": "2015-09-08 22:33:33",
        "updated_at": "2015-09-08 22:33:33",
        "images": ['\"236.jpg\"','\"504.jpg\"','\"784.jpg\"']
      }, {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "fasdf",
        "description": "asdfghjkl",
        "size": "fasdf",
        "color": "5a72fb",
        "created_at": "2015-09-09 11:48:31",
        "updated_at": "2015-09-09 11:48:31",
        "images": ['\"910.jpg\"','\"504.jpg\"','\"784.jpg\"']
      }]
    }

  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
<div ng-repeat="x in p.info">
  {{ x.images[0] +" are first"}}
</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the working [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/KunrFlU2K0KTOCelD0Ur?p=preview) for your code

Hope it helps you to understand :)

Comment: Please see my code again. I have updated the question.

Comment: and now if I want to take the first value of images "236.jpg", what I have to do ?

Comment: I am taking the array from PHP file. So how I will manage to make the array like you did now ? My PHP code is json_encode JSON